# Bootstrap dropdowns in internet explorer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a small issue.
If I have `<select>` in my html, and I apply the form-control class to it, it looks really weird in Internet Explorer, where it looks awesome in Chrome.

My code ends up simply being: `<select class="form-control"></select>`

Can I do something to fix this?

My example is directly from http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every browser renders UI styles differently. It's unlikely that your website visitors will be viewing your website in more than one browser at a time. User controls are common web page elements and your mobile users will thank you for not screwing their mobile experience on your website.

However if there is a design requirement for a custom UI control you'd design a custom select drop-down using HTML, CSS and add behavior layer with a JavaScript library like jQuery or use CSS3 if you don't need support for IE 7 - 9. Also make sure that it works fine on mobile devices, or replace a custom control with a native control at a certain screen resolution. This will depend on a scale of a project and time constraint.

At the very least you can use one of the Bootstrap custom drop-down controls. They will look similar in most browsers.

Comment: I didn't realize they had a dropdown class. That will work for me. I just want the experience to be the exact same (or as close to as possible) on all browsers.